# JQuery Unbind event when removing a class

Tags: jquery

So I have a couple of divs with a class "turn". Then in Jquery I have

```
$(".turn").click(function(){
   ...some code...
   if (..) $(this).removeClass("turn");
});
```

which I expect to remove the handler, so I can't click on it anymore. But I still want to be able on the other divs that has that class.
This is not working (I believe is because JQuery doesn't remove the handlers when a class is removed)
I've also tried with

```
$('.turn?).live(click,...) and $(this).die()
```

and

```
$('.turn?).bind()/$(this).unbind()
```

But neither of those seems to work. 
Can I get some hint about how to do this? 
Thanks

Comment: you are correct, once the .bind() function has been executed, jquery won't just remove handlers automatically like that

Answer (score 3):

The correct method for this is to use [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

```
$(".turn").click(function(){
   ...some code...
   if (..) $(this).unbind("click");
});
```

Comment: you should have $(".turn") not $("turn")

Comment: @joseph But that would unbind the click method for all the elements with "turn" class. And I don't want that.

Comment: @user950317 no, it'd be fine.  You telling it to only unbind the click event of `this`, which is the currently clicked `.turn`.  It would only unbind the one clicked.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do, but it wasn't working, I don't know why. Anyway, I've modified the code and now is working. So thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @user950317 ok.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help, but I'm glad you got it working. :)